# Webpack not compiling scss to css

Tags: css, webpack, sass

I'm building an app using webpack, babel, and Sass. Everything working fine but sass file not compiling css file even though it's not throwing any errors.
My Packages related to this are:

"webpack": "^3.10.0",

"css-loader": "^0.28.9",

"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",

"glob-all": "^3.1.0",

"node-sass": "^4.7.2",

"purify-css": "^1.2.5",

"purifycss-webpack": "^0.7.0",

"sass-loader": "^6.0.6"

`webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const glob = require('glob-all');
var PurifyCSSPlugin= require('purifycss-webpack'); 

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'dist/js/bundle.js'
  },
  watch: true,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['env', 'stage-3'],
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test:/\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: [ 
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                url: false
              }
            }
          ]
        })
      },
      {
        test:/\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: [ 
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                url: false
              }
            },
            'sass-loader'
          ]
        })
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: './dist/css/styles.css'
    }),
    new PurifyCSSPlugin({
      paths: glob.sync([
        path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'),
        path.join(__dirname, 'src/js/*.js')
      ])
    })
  ]
}
```

Files Directory:
[This is my project Files Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZZeB.png)

Comment: Can you show where you are loading the style such as css, scss, etc...

Comment: Be aware that you have to add `lang="scss"` to the style tags for this to work. Not `type="scss"`.

Comment: `loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']`

Comment: @s84 image added

Comment: @sultanaslam I mean add the code that loads the style such as style tag, require, etc.. to this question so we can see how webpack finds it

Comment: @s84 Thanks bro. i forget to import my SCSS file. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
test:/\.scss$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      use: [ 
        {
          loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
          options: {
            url: false
          }
        },
      ]
    })
```